# Using Spring and @IfProfileValue how to get only a certain method to run

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I have a test class and pom as visible here:

https://gist.github.com/llaskin/8319222

When I run the maven command `mvn clean test -Dtest.profile.discriminator=Twitter` my goal is only to have `testNumber2()` run, as its the only test that has the appropriate `test.profile.discriminator`, however instead I get all the tests in the class running(1,2,3).

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the following annotation to your class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = YourConfig.class /* or some xml file */)
@ProfileValueSourceConfiguration
```

so that JUnit uses Spring's test runner and not the default one.

Comment: I have updated my gist: https://gist.github.com/llaskin/8319222   and yet it still has the same reaction(runs all tests)

Comment: @llaskin If you don't want the other methods to run, you have to put an `@IfProfileValue` annotation with a value that is not in system properties.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  `@Test` annotations. They are causing to run all test cases.